# mod_rewrite: environment variables aren't being expanded in RewriteConds

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I've got a `RewriteCond` in a `.htaccess` similar to:

```
RewriteCond "%{ENV:FOO}" =bar
```

But the `${ENV:FOO}` is being expanded to the value of `FOO`, it's always blank.

For example, if I `SetEnv FOO "bar"` just before the `RewriteCond`, then crank up the `RewriteLogLevel`, I get this in my rewrite log:

```
RewriteCond: input='' pattern='=bar' => not-matched
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can I make environment variables expand inside of `RewriteCond`s?

Also, if I add a silly `RewriteRule` like `RewriteRule .* %{ENV:FOO}`, I can see in the rewrite log that the variable is being correctly expanded there.

My Apache version is 2.2.17.

**Edit**: I've found [another reference](http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=111106) to this problem. It seems like a “solution” is to use `SetEnvIf` instead of `SetEnv`… =\

Additionally, it doesn't seem like the location of the `SetEnv` has any effect. I've put it both in httpd.conf and in the `.htaccess`, and neither work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, here we go. From the [SetEnv documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/env.html) (under "caveats"):

> The SetEnv directive runs late during request processing meaning that directives such as SetEnvIf and RewriteCond will not see the variables set with it.

So, for now, I guess I'm using:

```
SetEnvIf _ .* FOO=bar
```

Comment: Woot! I've been fighting with this for days. Thanks!

Comment: I've been trying to find some reference documentation about that underscore character that you've used. Any pointers?